# JSON parsing php issue

Tags: php, json, parsing

I have this json response

```
 {"success":true,"results":[{"response":["random1"],"id":"6566","Limit":1},{"response":["random2"],"id":"6563","Limit":1},{"response":["random3"],"id":"6568","Limit":1}]}
```

All I need is to extract the random1,random2,random,3 from response so the final results will be:

- random1
- random2
- random3

I have this script

```
$jsonData = file_get_contents("json");

$json = json_decode($jsonData,true); 

foreach($json["results"][0]["response"] as $data) {
 {
   echo json_encode($data);

}
}
```

But this will extract only

- random1

If I change `[0]` in `[1]` will extract the random2 and `[2]` random3 
How can I get random1,random2,random3, response at once? so the final echo will be:

- random1
- random2
- random3

Thank you in advance, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop at your `$json['result']` what your doing is only taking the first index `0` which have `random1` as its `response` value

```
$json = '{"success":true,"results":[{"response":["random1"],"id":"6566","Limit":1},{"response":["random2"],"id":"6563","Limit":1},{"response":["random3"],"id":"6568","Limit":1}]}';
$json = json_decode($json,true); 

foreach($json["results"] as $data) {
   echo $data['response'][0]."\n";
}
```

Try it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a437f9cf8a851f77f95ed89eb72e63024e831495)

---

**Update**

if you want to filter let's say `random1` then do like this

```
$json = json_decode($json,true); 
$filter = array("random1"); //You can add items to filter
$result = array();
foreach($json["results"] as $data) {
   if(!in_array($data['response'][0],$filter))
       $result[] = $data;
}
print_r($result);
```

`$result` will contain only `random2` & `random3`

Comment: @AlexandruVorobchevici No problem. glad i helped.  Make sure to accept answers for future references and help others with the same problem.

Comment: Is any change to insert a word filter in this? so I can filter some words I have tried with  if(strpos($data, 'random1') !== false) but won't work

Comment: @AlexandruVorobchevici what kind of words? `random1` to `random3`?

Comment: Let's say I wanna filter random1.. so the final result will be random2 and random3

Comment: the json output data will be larger that in example : something like '{"success":true,"results":[{"response":["goodword"],"id":"6566","Limit":1},{"response":["badword"],"id":"6563","Limit":1},{"response":["goodword"],"id":"6568","Limit":1},{"response":["badword"],"id":"6564","Limit":1},{"response":["goodword"],"id":"6560","Limit":1},{"response":["badword"],"id":"6569","Limit":1},{"response":["goodword"],"id":"6566","Limit":1}]}' and i wanna filter badword

Comment: what your'e saying is you want the result of an `array` that only consist's of `goodword`?

Comment: @AlexandruVorobchevici see the Update answer

Comment: Thank you again, is working but now the final results is this : 'Array ( [0] => Array ( [response] => Array ( [0] => random2 ) [id] => 6563 [Limit] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [response] => Array ( [0] => random3 ) [id] => 6568 [Limit] => 1 ) )'   and i need only random2 and random3 without  Array ( [response] , id etc  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8a4e8808ad6a26b400375a27964b0b76d9535351

Comment: Fixed with foreach($json["results"] as $data) {
  if(preg_match('/^(badword)$/i',$data['results'][0])) continue;  
  echo $data['answers'][0]."\n";
}  Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`results` is an array, so you got the first one in the array by this: `$json["results"][0]`.

If you want to iterate all the values, it should be like this:

```
foreach($json["results"] as $data) {
   echo json_encode($data['response']);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($json["results"] as $data) {    echo json_encode($data['response']);}
```